# How do I add an object property to the object's attributes?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model, eloquent

I have the following on an Eloquent model:

```
public function setGameName(\Game $game)
{
    $this->gameName = $game->find($this->gameId)->name;
}
```

When I use `dd()` on the model before using `toArray()`, I get the following:

```
Promotion {#251 ▼
  #table: "Promotion"
  #primaryKey: "promotionId"
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #game: null
  +gameName: "3Peaks"
  #connection: null
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:14 [▶]
  #original: array:14 [▶]
  #relations: array:5 [▶]
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #fillable: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
}
```

As you can see, `gameName` is outside of `attributes` and `original`. If I run `toArray()` on the model at this point, the returned array has no `gameName` property, which I need. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set it on `$this->attributes`, snake cased:

```php
public function setGameName(\Game $game)
{
    $this->attributes['game_name'] = $game->find($this->gameId)->name;
}
```